# How to plot graph in Qt using the data received from serial port?

Tags: qt, qt4, qwt

I have successfully communicated with one of my ARM7 board through serial port in Qt using `qextserialport`.

Now I have the data with me. I want to use it to plot graph (realtime plot), so, can anybody tell me how to do it?

If possible please, provide the sample example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qwt offers several optimizations how to implement real time plots - f.e in opposite to all other Qt plot packages it offers incremental painting.

You can check the oscilloscope example to see what is possible without almost no CPU usage.

Having to repaint from scratch for every incoming sample is the worst case, but even then there are strategies to speed up the repaints. But what optimzations are possible depends on your specific situation and can't be answered in general.

But if you need support for the Qwt library it doesn't make much sense to ask anywhere ales beside on the official Qwt support channels you can find on the Qwt project page !

Answer (score 2):

I think what you looking for is this
http://www.workslikeclockwork.com/index.php/components/qt-plotting-widget/

Comment: That's great widget! If you want just simple graphics that is perfect for you. 

Else, there is really Qwt library.

Comment: Thanks thehilmisu,thats the complete set which i was needed.Thank you very much!!